# Jquery - Parsing text in JSON string for cross-references when loading

Tags: jquery, regex, json

I have some JSON data that looks like this (title, desc):

```
   var dreams = [
      { "keyword": "Abandon", "desc": "Difficulty framing plans..." },
      { "keyword": "Abandonment", "desc": "Your unconscious may be giving you messages..." },
      { "keyword": "Abbess", "desc": "Do you even know what an Abbess is?" },
      { "keyword": "Abbey", "desc": "Wedding or funeral?" },
      { "keyword": "Abbot", "desc": "I smell treachery!" },
      { "keyword": "Abbreviations", "desc": "WTF, IDK" },
      { "keyword": "Abdomen", "desc": "Time for a diet" }
    ]
```

I'm using jQuery Autocomplete to make suggestions in a text field, that all works fine. What I'd like to do is parse the description of the selected term and look for other keywords (titles) from the same JSON source, and if I find something, wrap the match in a link, thus creating internal hyperlinks from one source.

For example if I selected 'Abandon' and within the description was a mention (or mentions) of 'Abbey', I'd like to wrap a link round those mentions.

What's the most efficient method of doing this? Parsing each word within the description and regexing against the JSON? Eventually there might be 10,000 entries in that list. I have to do this client-side for the purposes of a demo; it might be that later I can move to node.js to do it server side more efficiently, but for now it needs to work in jQuery.

Comment: there are several js libraries for `fuzzy search`

Comment: I've looked at list.js and fuse.js but I can't quite see how I can apply them to this situation. I'm wondering if I need to do something like:

`var str = description.split(" ");`
`$(str).each(function(){ /*look up description in JSON and do something if found*/ });`

but I think that might be a horribly innefficient approach... :/

Comment: Sorry I can't format my comment for some reason

Comment: for absolute match that should work. Your example made it look like you needed something fuzzier than that. Would at least get prototype working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so in case this is useful for anyone, I ended up using Julian Shapiro's excellent blast.js (http://julian.com/research/blast/), and put together a simple demo using the following code (keeping the same JSON data above)

```
$.each(dreams, function(index, element) {
  if (element.value != suggestion.value) {
    $("#pageBody").blast({
      search: element.value,
      tag: 'a'
    });
  }
});
```

This simply wraps an  tag (no destination yet) around any matches that it finds. I had to add some keywords to the descriptions so that it could find something, but it works, and very quickly too.